# SQL script to show current week and first week of every month

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have written sql code to pull all the data that I need but the startdate is in weeks.  I need to see the current week and then for future dates I need to see the first date of each month.  (Like I said these are in weeks and the date is each Monday. (ex. 03-JUN-19, 10-JUN-19, 17-JUN-19....)

```
select 
d.ITEM,
i.DESCRIPTION,
d.MARKET,
(CASE
WHEN d.LOC like 'U%' THEN 'US'
WHEN d.LOC like 'M%' THEN 'MX'
WHEN d.LOC like 'C%' THEN 'CA'
ELSE 'EXP' END) as COUNTRY,
d.START_DATE as STARTDATE,
SUM(d.DEMANDQTY) as QTY

from DEMAND d, ITEM i
where d.ITEM = i.ITEM 
GROUP BY d.ITEM, i.DESCRIPTION, d.MARKET, d.LOC,d.START_DATE
```

So if I pulled this data today (7-JUN-19) I would need to only pull dates that are...03-JUN-19, 01-JUL-19, 05-AUG-19, 02-SEP-19, 07-OCT-19, 04-NOV-19, 02-DEC-19, 06-JAN-20 on and on until the data is done.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *calendar* which will return desired dates - the first Monday (that follows *today*), and then the first Monday in every month. Here's how:

```
SQL> with
  2  this_year as
  3    (select trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 datum
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= date '2019-12-31' - trunc(sysdate) + 1
  6    ),
  7  formatted as
  8    (select datum,
  9            to_char(datum, 'd') day_num,
 10            to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') day_name
 11     from this_year
 12    )
 13  select *
 14  from formatted f
 15  where 1 = 1
 16  and f.datum = (select min(f1.datum)
 17                 from formatted f1
 18                 where f1.day_num = 1
 19                   and to_char(f1.datum, 'yyyymm') = to_char(f.datum, 'yyyymm')
 20                );

DATUM      D DAY_NAME
---------- - ------------
10.06.2019 1 mon
01.07.2019 1 mon
05.08.2019 1 mon
02.09.2019 1 mon
07.10.2019 1 mon
04.11.2019 1 mon
02.12.2019 1 mon

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `this_year` CTE returns all dates from "today" to Dec 31st 2019. If there's some MAX date you can use - use it
- `formatted` CTE is an intermediate step; if you run it, you'll see that `day_num` represents ordinal number of a day (1, 2, ... 7), while `day_name` returns their abbreviate names (mon, tue, ...). We are interested in day number 1 as it represents Mondays
- the final `select` returns desired result - the first Monday in every month

Once you have those dates, use them in your current query. How? A simple option is to create a view based on such a query, e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace view v_mondays as
  2  with
  3  this_year as ...
  <snip>
View created.

SQL> select * From v_mondays;

DATUM      D DAY_NAME
---------- - ------------
10.06.2019 1 mon
01.07.2019 1 mon
<snip>
7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Expanded, your query might look like this:

```
select 
  d.item,
  i.description,
  d.market,
  case
    when d.loc like 'U%' then 'US'
    when d.loc like 'M%' then 'MX'
    when d.loc like 'C%' then 'CA'
    else 'EXP' 
  end as country,
  d.start_date as startdate,
  sum(d.demandqty) as qty
from demand d join item i on d.item = i.item 
join v_mondays m on m.datum = d.start_date                   --> join with Mondays
group by d.item, i.description, d.market, d.loc,d.start_date;
```